# Updating column entry for List folder based on column entries for Items in folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, folder, flow

I"m very new to both SharePoint & Flow, so I appreciate any help on this issue. There is probably a better way to accomplish this as well, so any other directions you could point me would be great.

I'm attempting to create a master maintenance tracking list using a SharePoint list. This will have quite a few items in the list across several facilities so I would ideally like to organize the items into folders for facilities and/or individual pieces of equipment. I have a "Date Last Completed" column and a "Periodicity" column which are then used to calculate a "Date Due" column for each maintenance task. The problem comes when I try to organize them into folders. The folders in the list also have these columns, however because they are empty, the Date Due column is tabulated as some date far in the past and therefore is marked as past due with the conditional formatting I've set up.

What I have been attempting to do it write a Flow which will loop through all of the items in each folder, find the one with the earliest "Due Date" and then write the other 2 columns to the folder so that its Due Date field shows the date of the first task coming due within the folder. I haven't been even close to successful writing this Flow, it seems that my current issue is in trying to obtain any sort of link or ID to the folder created within the list so that I can reference the columns on the Folder instead of only the Items within the list.

Here is a screenshot of the basic list right now. I have the 2 items shown replicated inside the folder as well. What I would like to do is to copy the earliest DueDate from within the folder to the folder itself programmatically. I assume that I need to do this by copying (in this example) the values for Date Last Completed and Periodicity from "MFP-111 shaft rotation" to the folder.
[image]

For the Flow, what I've been trying to do is:

1. Use Get items to obtain every item in the list
2. Use Apply to each to loop through all the list entries to do the following:
3. Get folder metadata for each item (hoping that this would return the folder within the list, but this doesn't seem to be the case. It seems to return the folder the list resides in only)
4. Get item using the ItemID from step 3 to give me the list columns for the folder (this fails to run and gives an error that the item cannot be found).
5. Run update item to copy the pertinent fields from the task within the folder to the folder (this I assume will fail as I don't appear to be obtaining the ID for the list folder correctly).